# Error 403 while getting cfm page

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion

I have a very weird behavior from Coldfusion 8 and IIS 7.

On the IIS, a site is declared and one of the subsirectories is a virtual directory poiting to a local filesystem. Everything is working except for a subdirectory. All of the sudden, I get an error 403 Access Denied as soon as I try to access a subfolder.

I place a simple CFM page to make my tests:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <cfoutput>Test</cfoutput>
   </body>
</html>
```

This request works: `http://myserver/vDir/fckeditor/editor/test.cfm`

While this one triggers a 403: `http://myserver/vDir/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/test.cfm`

I checked the following and could not find any difference:

- NTFS rights -> same on both directories. The user running the
  ColdFusion service has 'Full Control'
- IIS Authentication -> same on both folders
- Authorization Rules -> same on both folders
- Handler Mappings -> same on both folders

I turned on the Failed Request Tracing and added a rule to capture the event. It appears that the wildcard Coldfusion ISAPI filter is actually throwing the exception:

> CALL_ISAPI_EXTENSION:
>
> DllName *ColdfusionInstallationPath*\runtime\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll
>
> MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS:
>
> ModuleName IsapiModule
>
> Notification 128
>
> HttpStatus **403**
>
> HttpReason **Access denied**.
>
> HttpSubStatus 0
>
> ErrorCode 0
>
> ConfigExceptionInfo Notification
>
> EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)

Do anyone have a clue on how to solve this?

P.S. This question is cross-posted on StackOverflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270560/error-403-while-getting-cfm-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this article](http://www.ephost.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=212), which seems to describe exactly what you're seeing.